# overlapping date intervals with gaps

Tags: r, data.table

I have been trying to find an elegant data.table solution (but I will take another if there is something better) on how to combine date intervals that deals with (1) nested intervals, (2) intervals with varying priorities, and (3) intervals with gaps (see example input object). I managed to find a nearly successful solution via foverlaps and shift. I am hoping to avoid for/while loops or cartesian products, both which are inefficient and inelegant, but will definitely work. I am hoping that there is something better since this is a common data issue I must deal with. Upon request, I will show my nearly effective solution, if that would be useful.

```
require(data.table)
# my data looks somewhat like this...
input <- data.table(
  person_ID = c(rep(98723, 4), rep(8534, 2), 11223, rep(22446, 2)),
  team = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2), "A", "B", "A"),
  start_date = as.Date(c("2009-10-1", "2011-11-21", "2012-1-23", "2013-3-2", 
    "2009-11-14", "2010-1-1", "2012-1-2", "2011-2-2", "2012-4-3")),
  end_date = as.Date(c("2010-5-23", NA, "2015-01-02", "2013-3-2", "2009-12-31", 
    "2010-3-1", "2015-03-22", "2016-1-2", "2014-9-30")))
team_priority <- data.table(team = c("A", "B"), priority = c(1, 2))
input[team_priority, priority := i.priority, on = "team"]
```

**input**

```
  person_ID team start_date   end_date priority
1:     98723    A 2009-10-01 2010-05-23        1
2:     98723    A 2011-11-21       <NA>        1
3:     98723    A 2012-01-23 2015-01-02        1
4:     98723    A 2013-03-02 2013-03-02        1
5:      8534    B 2009-11-14 2009-12-31        2
6:      8534    B 2010-01-01 2010-03-01        2
7:     11223    A 2012-01-02 2015-03-22        1
8:     22446    B 2011-02-02 2016-01-02        2
9:     22446    A 2012-04-03 2014-09-30        1
# problem 1: gap in teams prevents simple min/max solution (see person_ID == 98723)

# problem 2: teams have priorities, so if team B is inside of time interval assigned to time A,
# then we need the records to reflect the following:
# team B -> team A -> team B based on when teams A & B start/stop (see person_ID == 22446)

# NOTE: problem 1 and 2 can be combined (I am trying to fix bad data entry)

# I have to assign priorities based on team involvement (A > B > C, etc)
output <- data.table(
  person_ID = c(rep(98723, 4), rep(8534, 2), 11223, rep(22446, 3)),
  team = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 2), "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  start_date = as.Date(c("2009-10-1", "2011-11-21", "2012-1-23", "2013-3-2", 
    "2009-11-14", "2010-1-1", "2012-1-2", "2011-2-2",  "2012-4-3", "2014-10-1")),
  end_date = as.Date(c("2010-5-23", NA, "2015-01-02", "2013-3-2", "2009-12-31", 
    "2010-3-1", "2015-03-22", "2012-4-2", "2014-9-30", "2016-1-2")),
  group_id = c(1, rep(2, 3), rep(4, 2), 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

**output**

```
    person_ID team start_date   end_date group_id
 1:     98723    A 2009-10-01 2010-05-23        1
 2:     98723    A 2011-11-21       <NA>        2
 3:     98723    A 2012-01-23 2015-01-02        2
 4:     98723    A 2013-03-02 2013-03-02        2
 5:      8534    B 2009-11-14 2009-12-31        4
 6:      8534    B 2010-01-01 2010-03-01        4
 7:     11223    A 2012-01-02 2015-03-22        5
 8:     22446    B 2011-02-02 2012-04-02        6
 9:     22446    A 2012-04-03 2014-09-30        7
10:     22446    B 2014-10-01 2016-01-02        8
```

A simple MIN/MAX solution will not work! I am not opposed to dealing with the nested intervals (see person_id == 22446) separately, but that is indeed the part I have been unable to figure out while still getting all the other goals met at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways to do this more efficiently. But I think this is better than nothing. If someone comes along with something better, awesome, I would happily choose their response. Perhaps I should have made this more palatable by breaking it up into sections, but if I had known what sections, I would not have had to ask in the first place. :) Anyway, here is my solution, I will make it more polished since it will go in my R package, but this at least answers the question in all the ways I have tested so far.

I had to break my wishes in that parts of this have for loops and one part of this makes use of a cartesian product. I could not think a way to avoid them (yet).

```
overlap_combine <- 
  function(overlap_dt, id_cols, team_col, start_col, end_col, overlap_int = 1L, 
           replace_blanks = Sys.Date(), priority_col = "priority") {
    setorderv(overlap_dt, c(id_cols, team_col, start_col))
    overlap_dt[, end_col := get(end_col) + overlap_int]
    sd_cols <- c(start_col, "end_col")
    # foverlaps cannot deal with blanks
    overlap_dt[is.na(end_col), end_col := replace_blanks]
    # note: if end_col becomes < start_col due to overlap_int,
    # we assign end_col <- start_col
    overlap_dt[end_col - get(start_col) < 0, end_col := start_col]
    overlap_dt[, index := .I]
    setnames(overlap_dt, start_col, "start_date")
    # setnames(overlap_dt, team_col, "team")
    # finding overlapping combinations via vectors of indices ---
    c_overlap <- 
      overlap_dt[overlap_dt[, unique(.SD), .SDcols = 
                              c(id_cols, team_col, "start_date", "end_col", "index")], 
                 on = c(id_cols, team_col), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
    c_overlap <- c_overlap[i.index != index]
    c_overlap[between(i.start_date, start_date, end_col) |
                between(i.end_col, start_date, end_col), 
              ovr_vec := list(list(unique(c(index, i.index)))), 
              by = c(id_cols, team_col, "start_date")]
    ovr_l <- c_overlap[, ovr_vec]
    ovr_l <- Filter(Negate(function(x) is.null(unlist(x))), ovr_l)
    ovr_l <- unique(ovr_l)
    # find list of reduced vectors which we need to MIN/MAX ---
    ovr_red_l <- list()
    for (i in seq_along(ovr_l)) {
      tmp_inter <- unique(unlist(sapply(
        ovr_l,
        FUN = function(x) {
          if (length(intersect(unlist(x), unlist(ovr_l[i]))) > 0) {
            result <- union(unlist(x), unlist(ovr_l[i]))
            return(result)
          } else {
            return(ovr_l[i])
          }
        }
      )))
      ovr_red_l[[i]] <- sort(tmp_inter)
    }
    ovr_red_l <- unique(ovr_red_l)

    for (i in seq(ovr_red_l)) {
      setkey(overlap_dt, index)[ovr_red_l[[i]],
                                c("start_date", "end_date", "end_col") := 
                                  list(min(start_date), max(end_date), max(end_col))]
    }
    overlap_dt[, index := NULL]
    overlap_dt <- unique(overlap_dt)
    setkeyv(overlap_dt, c(id_cols, "start_date"))
    # figure out which intervals are nested, separate them out & deal with them
    overlap_dt[, index := .I]
    overlap_dt[, prior_shift := priority - shift(priority, n = 1), by = id_cols]
    overlap_dt[between(shift(start_date, n = 1), start_date, end_col), ovr_shift := 1, by = id_cols]
    overlap_dt[shift(ovr_shift) == 1 & prior_shift < 0, nested_ovr := 1]
    overlap_dt[index %in% overlap_dt[nested_ovr == 1, index - 1], nested_ovr := 1]
        overlap_nested_dt <- overlap_dt[nested_ovr == 1]
    overlap_dt <- overlap_dt[is.na(nested_ovr)]
    nested_melt_dt <- 
      melt(overlap_nested_dt, id.vars = c(id_cols, team_col, priority_col), 
           measure.vars = c("start_date", "end_col"), value.name = "date_value")
    setkey(nested_melt_dt, person_ID, date_value)
    nested_melt_dt[, boundaries := cumsum(ifelse(variable == "start_date", 1, -1))]
    nested_melt_dt[boundaries==1 & variable == "start_date", bound_ok := 1]
    nested_melt_dt[boundaries==0 & variable == "end_col", bound_ok := 1]
    # create new records that need to be added ---
    add_dt <- nested_melt_dt[0, ]
    if (nrow(nested_melt_dt)>0) {
      for (i in 1:nrow(nested_melt_dt))
        if (nested_melt_dt[i, is.na(bound_ok)]) {
          if (nested_melt_dt[i, variable] == "start_date") {
            add_dt <- rbindlist(list(add_dt, 
                                     data.table(nested_melt_dt[i, person_ID],
                                                nested_melt_dt[i-1, team],
                                                nested_melt_dt[i-1, priority],
                                                "end_col", 
                                                nested_melt_dt[i, date_value - 1],
                                                NA, NA)))
          } else if (nested_melt_dt[i, variable] == "end_col") {
            add_dt <- rbindlist(list(add_dt, 
                                     data.table(nested_melt_dt[i, person_ID],
                                                nested_melt_dt[i+1, team],
                                                nested_melt_dt[i+1, priority],
                                                "start_date", 
                                                nested_melt_dt[i, date_value + 1],
                                                NA, NA)))
          }
        }
    }
    # add new records back in
    nested_melt_dt <- rbindlist(list(nested_melt_dt, add_dt))
    setkeyv(nested_melt_dt, c(id_cols, "date_value"))
    nested_melt_dt[, c("bound_ok", "boundaries") := NULL]
    nested_melt_dt[, date_group := .I, by = id_cols]
    nested_melt_dt[variable == "end_col", date_group := date_group - 1L]
    nested_melt_dt <-
      dcast(nested_melt_dt, paste0(paste(id_cols, sep = "+"), "+", team_col, "+",  
                                   priority_col, "+", "date_group ~ variable"), value.var = "date_value")
    nested_melt_dt[, end_date := end_col]
    nested_melt_dt[, c("date_group") := NULL]
    overlap_dt[,  c("index", "prior_shift", "ovr_shift", "nested_ovr") := NULL]
    overlap_dt <- rbindlist(list(overlap_dt, nested_melt_dt), use.names = TRUE)
    setorderv(overlap_dt, c(id_cols, start_col, team_col))
    return(overlap_dt)
  }
overlap_combine(overlap_dt = copy(input), id_cols = "person_ID", 
                team_col = "team", start_col = "start_date", end_col = "end_date", 
                overlap_int = 1L, replace_blanks = Sys.Date() + 1e3, 
                priority_col = "priority")
```

**function output**

```
   person_ID team start_date   end_date priority    end_col
1:      8534    B 2009-11-14 2010-03-01        2 2010-03-02
2:     11223    A 2012-01-02 2015-03-22        1 2015-03-23
3:     22446    B 2011-02-02 2012-04-02        2 2012-04-02
4:     22446    A 2012-04-03 2014-10-01        1 2014-10-01
5:     22446    B 2014-10-02 2016-01-03        2 2016-01-03
6:     98723    A 2009-10-01 2010-05-23        1 2010-05-24
7:     98723    A 2011-11-21       <NA>        1 2018-12-17
```